# Simplest way to support interactive mockup prototype in iOS?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uibutton, nib

I have 40 images that represent screen mockups of an iOS application. I will display each one full screen as an `UIImageView`. I want to support navigation from 1-40 through a button on each screen. I will add transparent `UIButton`s where I want to support this navigation. The buttons will not be in the same position on each screen.

Is my only option to create 40 nibs and draw by hand where I want these buttons? Am I missing some opportunity for a base class here? My images are predictably named, so I am planning on having the simple navigation methods in the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this: have one UIImageView and a view controller. The view controller has an NSArray, say `buttonsOnPage`. Inside the array, you'd store more NSArrays storing buttons. These buttons all point to the same action, say, `buttonPressed:`. Remember that you can assign `tag`s, you could use these to determine to which "page" to go. Since loading your images seems to be straight-forward I'm skipping this here.

Here's a little pseudo code:

```
- (void)initButtons
{
    NSMutableArray *page;
    UIButton *button;

    buttonsOnPage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Page 0
    page = [NSMutableArray array];

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvent:UIEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTag:5]; // When pressed, go to page 5.
    [button setFrame:...];
    [page addObject:button];
    ...
    [buttonsOnPage addObject:page];

    ...
}

- (void)setUpPage:(NSUInteger)page
{
    // Remove all previous buttons
    for (UIView *view in [myImageView subviews]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    for (UIButton *button in [buttonsOnPage objectAtIndex:page]) {
       [myImageView addSubview:button];
    }

    // Also set the correct image.
}


- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self setUpPage:[(UIView *)sender tag]];
}
```

You can make your button setup method easier/faster to type by defining a macro:

```
#define NEW_BUTTON(page, x, y, width, height) \
    do {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; \
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvent:UIEventTouchUpInside];\
        [button setTag:page]; \
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)]; \
        [page addObject:button];
    } while (0);
```

Then it's quite fast to do:

```
// Page 0
page = [NSMutableArray array];
NEW_BUTTON(1, 10, 20, 20, 20);
NEW_BUTTON(2, 10, 60, 20, 20);
[buttonsOnPage addObject:page];

// Page 1
page = [NSMutableArray array];
NEW_BUTTON(3, 70, 20, 20, 20);
NEW_BUTTON(4, 10, 160, 20, 20);
[buttonsOnPage addObject:page];

...
```

Comment: But you're assuming I know my button coordinates, which I don't. I still think I'll have to lay the buttons down manually.

Comment: Of course I assume you know the button coordinates, won't they be on fixed positions on each page ? If not, are they positioned randomly ?

Comment: Well, each screen is different, and they are all mockups. The button is on a different position on each screen (or enough of them, anyway).

Comment: @pkananen: And on each page, you know where the buttons are to be positioned since you've got the mockups, don't you ? You can just measure with The Gimp or similar tool where to position each button, right ?

Comment: I probably could, but at that point, I don't think I'm saving much time. I had a feeling there wasn't a lot I could optimize, here.

Comment: If I had coords, this would've been super helpful. Without them, it was still interesting and helpful.